# Breakpad Client not generated when cross-compiling

Tags: c++, c, compilation, google-breakpad

I'm trying to cross-compile Google Breakpad. I'm executing the following commands:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/breakpad CFLAGS="-Os" CC=PATH_ARM_COMPILER/arm-linux-gcc CXX=PATH_ARM_COMPILER/arm-linux-g++ --host=arm
$ make
$ make install
```

It generates and installs some files in the prefix path. In the include path it has:

```
|-common
|-google_breakpad
|-processor
```

but it should has:

```
|-client
|-common  
|-google_breakpad
|-processor
|-third_party
```

It seems to be a problem related to Breakpad client. What should be the right way to cross-compile Breakpad?

My host is a Ubuntu 18.04 x86-64, target ARM-32.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your problem on my side. In fact, the issue is related to `--host` compilation flag.
[Breakpad documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad/) shows that:

> when building on Linux it will also build the client libraries.

So, In order to get the client binaries and headers, you should use the correct compiler prefix.
For example if you are using the GNU cross compiler `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`, the --host flag value should be `arm-linux-gnueabihf`.
In your case (arm-linux-gcc) try to change your configure command as following:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/breakpad CFLAGS="-Os" CC=PATH_ARM_COMPILER/arm-linux-gcc CXX=PATH_ARM_COMPILER/arm-linux-g++ --host=arm-linux
```